# Parsing JSON data with Jansson library functions in linux

Tags: c, json

I have just implemented very simple JSON data parser code in C but it is not working as expected.

This is the JSON format I have done the coding, `{"check":"5"}`. And my code is:

```
params = json_loads(myJsonString, JSON_DECODE_ANY, &error);
//free(myJsonString);

if(!params)
{
    printf("Unable to load parmaters! error: on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
    return OTAL_ERR_INTERNAL;
}
```

I am always getting this error:

```
Unable to load parmaters! error: on line 1: string or '}' expected near 'check'
```

Comment: Without seeing implementation, there is not much any one can do.

Comment: And by the way, the above is CALLING code, not the implementation itself (assuming you know the difference)

Comment: I think OP is using `jansson` JSON parser. If so, @user2567627 please tag this Q with json and jansson and any more if appropriate

Comment: Are you sure abut the contents of `myJsonString` ? My implementation (using Jansson 2.0.1 with some minor customizasions) decodes `{"check":"5"}` perfectly. Maybe you print that string and error.column in case of error.

Comment: Works for me too with version 2.4. Try testing with the literal string `myJsonString = "{\"check\":\"5\"}";`.